# Load other entities by class name and id fields in Entity on Doctrine and Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, orm, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I am looking an approach for following case. I do have an entity which keeps information about other entity which could be any type of entuty. The subentity is recognized by field combination `subject_class` and `subject_id`. Is there a way that Doctrine would automatically fetch this subentity whenever I am fetching the parent?

Parent entity example:

```
<?php

namespace Yolo\RandomBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(
 *      uniqueConstraints={
 *          @ORM\UniqueConstraint(columns={"subject_id", "subject_class"})
 *      }
 * )
 */
class SwagRelation
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    private $subjectClass;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $subjectId;

    /**
     * @var object
     */
    private $subject;

    /**
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * @return object
     */
    public function getSubject()
    {
        // Here should be returned an entity got from subject class and id!
        return $this->subject;
    }

    /**
     * @param object $subject
     *
     * @return SwagRelation
     */
    public function setSubject($subject)
    {
        $this->subject = $subject;
        $this->subjectClass = get_class($subject);
        $this->subjectId = $subject->getId();

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An approach for the case would be to use a [Strategy-Pattern](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/cookbook/strategy-cookbook-introduction.html).